# Menu Merging Over References (.dll and .exe)

Tags: c#, merge, mdi

I have stumbled across an unusual problem whilst attempting to menu merge with Mdi. Basically, I have an MdiParent form which I have created in one solution, it will be the parent of a variety of MdiChild forms, which I have created in other projects and solutions, which will be referenced too in the MdiParent Project, the reference will be to the .exe of each mdi child form type.

I have tested the properties that I am using but within the same project and the menu merging works perfectly between MdiChild and Parent. But when I use the same merge code but in the instance of which I have referenced to the .exe of the project that contains my MdiChild, I have no success. I was wondering if there was a workaround for this? Or a solution.

The reason I am referencing the .exe's is because themselves are projects that can be independant, and are not only used by the MdiParent form that I have created.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I believe its to do with the object type loaded in to separate app domains which then make them different types (Could be wrong here...)

Have you thought of having the parents / child in the a single class library and having you're other projects reference that?